# WCF services cannot be found by my Javascript code

Tags: web-services, wcf, service

My service provider has migrated my code to a new server, and my WCF services can no longer be found by my AJAX code.  The message I get from the browser is:

HTTP404: NOT FOUND – The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).  GET – http://www.example.com/WebServices/TBox.svc/js

If I browse directly to the web service on my local PC (http://localhost:64805/WebServices/TBox.svc), I get a message ‘This is a Windows© Communication Foundation service. ….’. But if I  browse on my hosted service, I get a 404 Page Not Found error.

I’m attaching a section from my web.config, as I suspect it may have something to do with that.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="TimeboxAspNetAjaxBehavior">
          <enableWebScript />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="TBoxAspNetAjaxBehavior">
          <enableWebScript />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="WebMethodForTestingAspNetAjaxBehavior">
          <enableWebScript />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <services>
      <service name="Timebox">
        <endpoint address="http://www.example.com/WebServices/Timebox.svc" behaviorConfiguration="TimeboxAspNetAjaxBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Timebox" />
      </service>
      <service name="TBox">
        <endpoint address="http://www.example.com/WebServices/TBox.svc" behaviorConfiguration="TBoxAspNetAjaxBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="TBox" />
      </service>
      <service name="WebMethodForTesting">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="WebMethodForTestingAspNetAjaxBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WebMethodForTesting" />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Regards,
Saul

Comment: If your code was working before: 'My service provider has migrated my code to a new server' it's likely there is an issue with whatever your service provider did rather than your code. Could be a dns issue, IP mapping issue etc.

Comment: Thanks Popo.   I've asked them to investigate but I'm not getting any joy, I suspect they really don't know what it could be.

Comment: It may because of DNS problem on your Router, or for test browse your service on port `80` not `64805` on local server if it will browsed on `http://localhost/WebServices/TBox.svc/js` then problem is about network.

Comment: Are there any problems with the client and server network? Use the ping command to troubleshoot. Also, how do you make sure the WCF service is deployed correctly?